# Which is the another option rather than LINQ to SQL in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

HI,
I am currently using the ASP.NET MVC pattern for my small application. I am using LINQ to SQL to manipulate with objects of model. I am using lambda and queries to manipulate. But as i found lot of limitations with LINQ to SQL concept I am planning to remove. so which is the best option rather than LINQ to SQL for manipulation with data in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Comment: It may be helpful if you included some of the limitations you ran into.  That would help people point you in a better direction.

Comment: +1 million votes to @R0MANARMY comment, as the question is now the answers will just be subjective based on personal preferences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Answer (score 1):

[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) or [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) if you want something similar to LINQ to SQL but with a fuller feature set.

You might also want to check out [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) if you're familiar with the ActiveRecord pattern.

Answer (score 1):

- [Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)
- [Castle Project ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/)

Answer (score 0):

One popular and widely used/supported option for an ORM is [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx).